# awk or sed - print multiple pattern with variable in one line

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, awk, sed

```
for array in $arrays; do 
  count=$(sed '/Error/!d;/$array/!d' $logfile | wc -l) 
  #awk -v array=$array "/Error/ && /$array/" $logpath | wc -l
  echo "$count - $array"
done
```

I know how to do it with grep but I cannot use it. Both patterns must be in the same line. I am looping through an array containing strings. Help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:
I am looking for the string "Error" and $array - which contains string that I am looping through. I am searching through a file and want to print all lines that has *both* the string "Error" and the value of the variable "$array" in *one line*.

Comment: show sample input and expected output

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Example input and output would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/.../` cannot contain references to `awk` variables; you need to use the equivalent

```
$0 ~ array
```

instead.

```
awk -v "array=$array" -v count=0 '/Error/ && $0 ~ array { count++} END {print count }'
```

(eliminating the need for `wc` as well).

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to print "0" instead of nothing?

Comment: Yes, you just need to initialize `count` to 0. (I mistakenly assumed that any undefined variable would default to 0 in any context.) I've updated the answer.

Comment: It worked. Thanks! This is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Hmm, it may be what you were looking for but it seems unlikely it's the right solution since you'd be calling it from a shell loop and that's always the wrong approach. You haven't shown us input and output yet but it's extremely likely you could do everything in one brief, simple, efficient, portable awk script. You do not need to init count, just change the END to `print count+0`.